# Querying the entity framework (4.1) DbContext does not return any results

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

Using Entity Framework 4.1 with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

I have a strongly typed DbContext (ctx in code) with IDbSet<Users> property which represents a table [Users] in the database.
When I execute:

```
var result = ctx.Users.ToList();
```

The **result.Count** is **0** as if there is nothing in the database although there are records in that table. I've checked the ctx.Database.Connection and it does have the right connection string.

I executed

```
ctx.Users.ToString()
```

to get the SQL that will be executed and when I execute the given statement in the SQL management studio I do get the list of users.

It seems as if the query is never executed and I am unable to detemine what could be the problem.

Comment: Use SQL profiler if you want to know if query is executed but this really looks like problem with connection string.

Comment: You can normally check if there was an exception with the connection string in the debugger.

Comment: Everything is fine. It did not read the correct connection string and it created an empty database instead :).
Thx everybody for the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine. It did not read the correct connection string and it created an empty database instead :). Thx everybody for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Do any other tables work ? That will prove the connection string.

When you test in management studio make sure you are connecting as the same user as your connection string.

If both those tests pass it may be an issue with the name 'Users'? (Users was OK as a name in 4.0 but I've not tried it in 4.1 so its a potential area to look at)

Comment: Everything is fine. It did not read the correct connection string and it created an empty database instead :). Thx everybody for the effort

Comment: Yes that's why I asked if other tables worked - my guess was the connection string.